# I can't use emoji.js

Tags: javascript, npm, emoji

I'd like to use https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji to convert :emoji inside colons: into actual emoji, like how it is implemented in Discord and Slack.

I installed the library with `npm i emoji-js` 
Then I put the following in the head of my HTML:

```
<link href="emoji.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="emoji.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the following at the top of my script:

```
var emoji = new EmojiConvertor();
```

However, not only does the rest of my script not work after this, I  also get the following errors in my dev console:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3001/emoji.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

The resource from “http://localhost:3001/emoji.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)


Uncaught ReferenceError: EmojiConvertor is not defined
```

Does anyone know how I can implement this library?

Comment: how are you setting up your local web server?

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm using node and express, sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1):

You should include the full path to the library in the `link` and `script` tags.

```
<link href="./node_modules/emoji-js/lib/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./node_modules/emoji-js/lib/emoji.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This worked, however I still get mismatch errors and the ReferenceError.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858758</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="emoji" style="text-align: center; font-size: 120px"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="module">
    import * as emoji from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-js@3.7.0/lib/emoji.js";
    const emojiConvertor = new EmojiConvertor();
    emojiConvertor.replace_mode = 'unified';
    document.getElementById('emoji').innerHTML = emojiConvertor.replace_colons(':smile:');
  </script>
</html>
```