# ReferenceError when referring to object from NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, emoji, referenceerror

I'm trying to use https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji to implement colon-to-emoji conversion. I installed its NPM package and put

```
<script src="../node_modules/emoji-js/lib/emoji.js" type="text/javascript;" charset="UTF-8;"></script>
```

in the head of my HTML to import the script.
I know this is the correct path because when I command-click it in VS Code it takes me to this file. I get no type mismatch errors in the dev console from this.

However, when I declare a new EmojiConvertor object at the top of my script with
`const emoji = new EmojiConvertor();`, the script no longer functions and I get a ReferenceError: `Uncaught ReferenceError: EmojiConvertor is not defined`.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the page has loaded can you successfully instantiate an `EmojiConvertor()` using the console?  `var test = new EmojiConvertor()` and then view that variable?

Comment: @DavidTansey I can't, it throws the same error

Answer (score 1):

The `script` declaration should not have a `;` in the `type="text/javascript;"` attribute.

This snippet with `text/javascript;` reproduces `ReferenceError`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858758</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="emoji" style="text-align: center; font-size: 120px"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-js@3.7.0/lib/emoji.js" type="text/javascript;" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script>
    const emojiConvertor = new EmojiConvertor();
    emojiConvertor.replace_mode = 'unified';
    document.getElementById('emoji').innerHTML = emojiConvertor.replace_colons(':smile:');
  </script>
</html>
```

The same snippet removing `;` and using just `text/javascript` solves `ReferenceError` and `emoji-js` works:

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858758</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="emoji" style="text-align: center; font-size: 120px"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-js@3.7.0/lib/emoji.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script>
    const emojiConvertor = new EmojiConvertor();
    emojiConvertor.replace_mode = 'unified';
    document.getElementById('emoji').innerHTML = emojiConvertor.replace_colons(':smile:');
  </script>
</html>
```